# Calculate time taken by PixiJs for initial render

Tags: javascript, graphics, pixi.js

How to calculate the time taken by PixiJs for initial render?
This is my function which renders thousand rectangles. I want to calculate the time taken by PixiJS to complete the initial render?
Is there any renderComplete event in PixiJS?

```
function createRectsUsingPixi (container, width, height, points) {
    const app = new PIXI.Application({ antialias: true, width, height });
    container.appendChild(app.view);

    const rect = new PIXI.Graphics();

    rect.beginFill(0x626262);

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        const { x, y, width, height } = points[i];
        rect.drawRect(x, y, width, height));
    }


    rect.endFill();
    app.stage.addChild(rect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example: https://codepen.io/domis86/pen/poJrKdq - and focus on following lines:

This creates Ticker and turns off "automatic rendering":

```
// See: https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Ticker_.html
let ticker = PIXI.Ticker.shared;
ticker.autoStart = false;
ticker.stop();
```

Then inside "game loop" we call `render` method manually:

```
renderer.render(app.stage);
```

This `render` method seems to be synchronous according to experts (including one of authors of pixi.js) here: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/5299 (comment about manual render: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/5299#issuecomment-449080238 ), and here: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/27849-detect-when-view-has-been-rendered/?do=findComment&comment=160061

So, you can calculate execution time of `render` method.

See also description how to setup "custom game loop" without "Ticker": https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/wiki/v5-Custom-Application-GameLoop#custom-gameloop

> Is there any renderComplete event in PixiJS?

You can try https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Renderer.html#postrender

Also additional performance tip: in your example i see that you create one `PIXI.Graphics` objects and draw many rectangles inside it. Please try creating one `PIXI.Graphics` per rectangle (draw one rectangle in one `PIXI.Graphics` object) and compare performance.

Also, usually you want to create `PIXI.Application` only once (at beginning of program). So line:

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({ antialias: true, width, height });
```

should be probably extracted from function `createRectsUsingPixi` and called separately elsewhere once.